# PHP ArrayObject insert inside the array

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures, arrayobject

How to insert a new value inside (***in the middle of the array**) the array of the **ArrayObject** 
I know how to do it when it's a plain array, like this:

```
$array_1 = array(
            '0' => 'zero',
            '1' => 'one',
            '2' => 'two',
            '3' => 'three',
        );
        echo "<pre>";
        array_splice($array_1, 2, 0, 'more');
        print_r($array_1);
```

But I don't know if the array is of type object like this:

```
$array_1 = new ArrayObject([  '0' => 'zero',
                '1' => 'one',
                '2' => 'two',
                '3' => 'three']);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use [`append()`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.append.php) like this:

```
$array_1 ->append('xy');
```

This does pretty much the same as `$array[] = "xy";` for normal arrays.

If you want to replace an arrayObject element just use [`offsetSet()`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.offsetset.php):

```
$array_1->offsetSet(2, "more");
```

**EDIT:**

Just use `getArrayCopy()` then you can use all array functions as you are familiar with:

```
$array_1 = $array_1->getArrayCopy();
array_splice($array_1, 2, 0, 'more');
$array_1 = new ArrayObject($array_1);
```

Comment: By **inside** I mean insert a new element in the middle of the array, not just appending to the end of the array.

Comment: @Amaynut As in my answer then use: `offsetSet()` to change an element in the middle

Comment: @Amaynut So where are we with this question?

Comment: with `offsetSet()` you will replace the element in the given offset, you cannot just inset a new one and shift the array indexes. Look at my example with a plain array, I'm inserting a new element in the middle of the array by using the function `array_splice($array_1, 2, 0, 'more');` I want to do the same thing for my object.

Comment: *I want to do the same thing for my object* So you want an implementation of `array_splice()` for `ArrayObject`, right?

Comment: No I just want to be able to insert a new value in the middle of the array object no matter the method. So easy to do in fully object oriented language like ruby. In Ruby I can do that with `array_1.insert(2, 'more')`.  But not so easy with in PHP.

Comment: it still not straight forward like the example I mentioned above with **Ruby**, but it works. This confirms the fact that PHP has many limitations when it comes to OOP.

Comment: @Amaynut No there is no function like in Ruby. But I think this is the best and easiest solution you can get, since you then can use all array function as you are familiar with and you don't have to create your own ones